# Eigenvalues of a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to rewrite this equation in matrix form and compute the eigenvalues.

$$\ddot{y}=-a\dot{y}-b(y-c)$$

I define $u_1=y-c$ and $u_2= \dot{y}$
so that I have a system of first-order equations \begin{align}
\dot{u}_1= \dot{y}=u_2\\
\dot{u}_2=-au_2-bu_1
\end{align}

In matrix form,     \begin{align} \begin{pmatrix}
   \dot{u}_1\\
   \dot{u}_2
  \end{pmatrix}  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1\\
   -b & -a
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
   u_1\\
   u_2
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
To find the eigenvalues, \begin{align}
-\lambda (-a - \lambda) + b = 0\\
\lambda^2 + a\lambda + b = 0\\
(\lambda+a)(\lambda+\frac{b}{a})=0
\end{align}
So I get $\lambda_1=-a$, $\lambda_2=-\frac{b}{a}$.

Does this look right?

Comment: Your factorisation of the quadratic is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is $\mu^2+a\mu+b$. The roots should match your Eigenvalues.

Consider reviewing your resolution of the quadratic equation.